# Why request is going to Struts Dispatcher?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, struts2

I have both Struts 2 and Spring MVC configured. My `web.xml` looks like below. When I hit a REST URL to upload file, it invokes struts dispatcher instead of Spring.

Why URL `/rest/uploadfile/iec9.pdf` is going to Struts Dispatcher?

**`web.xml`:**

```xml
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>springmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>springmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/springmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
<filter-name>jsonpCallbackFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
 
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>jsonpCallbackFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your spring MVC dispatcher servlet is mapped to the subset of URLs handled by the Struts filter. As far as filter invoked before any other servlets then it will have precedence. To workaround you need to configure Struts to exclude some URLs from mapping.

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/?.*"/>
    ...

</struts>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Roman’s answer, when configuring Struts and Spring MVC in the same project, it is common to use a struts exclude filter. When the request is made Struts will try to handle the request, when it is excluded Spring MVC will take over and handle the request. Is is worth noting that the Struts exclude filter can go in a properties file, such as a struts.properties. Often Regex can be used here in order to exclude a common phrase (like if all your actions or controllers in a class share a common part, you can exclude all using the Regex).